# UIDatePicker is crashing without a reason

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uidatepicker

I have set `UIDatePicker` in a cocos2d scene. (hope its right)
Its working great till the moment i have to pick a date, so i roll the picker and then the moment it stops, it crashes, and it doesnt even call the picker method.

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,250,0,0);

UIDatePicker *myPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[myPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//[self.view addSubview:myPicker];
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:myPicker];
[myPicker release];


- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"value: %@",[sender date]);

}
```

btw
did i add the picker to the cocos2d scene correctly?

Comment: replace `- (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender ` with `- (void)pickerChanged:(UIDatePicker*)sender` and check, whether this method is being called.

Comment: tried that , didnt help.

Comment: and its not being called -no nslog.

Answer (score 1):

It crashes when the picker try to call your method, but the target (`self`) may have been deallocated, so you should get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: This would be my bet, too. In fact, I'll go so far as to say you should just accept this answer *immediately*. Even if you don't believe it, even if it takes you weeks, this is going to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

date is a property not a function ... sender is a DatePicker in this case. The code below should work!

```
-(void)pickerChanged:(UIDatePicker*) datePicker{
    NSLog(@"value: %@",datePicker.date);
}
```

Comment: Properties are functions. Functions are not necessarily properties.